# What's the human behaviour called that often makes us warp realities to appease another?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Whenever people experience specific medical symptoms, they might research it online and find out that there is a possibility of a certain cancer being the culprit, they then might see that the chances of getting that cancer is 1 in a million. So they would often shrug it off as "Well that will never happen to me!", whereas that same person might go to the local store to purchase a lottery ticket that has a chance of winning set at 1 in 30 million and they then feel like the chance is high enough to win.

I am looking to find out if there is a particular name for this type of behaviour / thought process. I'm interested in research papers regarding these behaviours.

Comment: I think there's a lot in this interesting question. Possible terms that may contribute here are: [Confirmation Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias), [Planning Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_fallacy), certain kind of misalignment between Conscious and Subconscious i.e. [Self-Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-regulation_theory), further the non-intuitive nature of Statistic models and Game Theory. I guess other people have clarified this question already, so I would like to try to find a point or a paper to all this soon.

Comment: Also these seem to be important: [Loss Aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion), and [Risk Aversion](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/3655/relationship-between-cognitive-load-and-self-indulgent-behavior-in-simple-task-c). My guts tell me that there are soon enough mosaic stones for a reasoned answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [optimism bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_illusions#Types):

> ... a tendency for people to overestimate their likelihood of
>   experiencing a wide variety of pleasant events, such as enjoying their
>   first job or having a gifted child, and somewhat underestimate their
>   risk of succumbing to negative events, such as getting divorced or
>   falling victim to a chronic disease.

[Optimism bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimism_bias) is a type of [self-enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-enhancement):

> ... a preference for positive over negative self-views.

and [positive illusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_illusions):

> ... unrealistically favorable attitudes that people have towards
>   themselves or to people that are close to them.